# Is Android thread model one-to-one or many-to-one?

Tags: java, android, linux, multithreading

I'm confused of the thread model of Android. I'm stuck...:(

> Does Android implement one-to-one, or many-to-many?

From Stackoverflow/Googling/Books, I've learnt that Android uses a modified version of Linux pthread. I think it means that Android implement one-to-one Thread model. (i.e., one user thread per one kernel thread)

However, if I see the processes/threads using **ps -t** on Android devices, there's a lot of threads in a single application. For example, 2 kworkers and 14 other threads (ex. Binder, mali, JDWP, GCDaemon, etc.). From that fact, I think Android implements many-to-many Thread model. (i.e., M user threads to N kernel threads)
@ I've learnt that kworker is the kernel worker thread. Is it right to think that kworker is the kernel thread of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much nothing uses a many to one model these days.  They were useful in the bad old days when OSes didn't all support multithreading.  But there's pretty much 0 benefit from doing a many to one on any modern OS, especially not Linux.  Its interesting to learn about from a theoretical standpoint, or to implement to understand how scheduling works without having to muck with a kernel.  But its not something anyone uses.

Really what would the benefit be?  Having an idle kernel thread has no negatives other than a tiny amount of memory.  So why not use a kernel thread?

Comment: Yes..You're right.  But my question is that whether Android implements one-to-one or many-to-many...not many-to-one. ^^;

Comment: Same answer.  There's 0 advantage to multiplexing on a kernel thread.  Also, ps can only list kernel level threads.

Comment: Oh you meant that Android implements one-to-one model? And more, I didn't knew that ps only list kernel level threads. Thanks. :)

Comment: ps queries the kernel for its information on threads.  In a many to 1 or many to many model the kernel has no idea that a kernel thread is being used for multiple pseudo-threads.  That's something only that's totally opaque to the OS and to any other app.